# Salesforce communities how to edit CSS

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-communities

I need help in how to identify which .Class CSS in communities I have to edit?

I am able to inspect the what changes needs to be done but unable to understand that in communities how do I edit it as I cannot find the class in it.[Issue with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKN1M.jpg).

I am able to inspect it, but when I try to edit my changes made to communities, I am unable to find .slds-size_2-of-12 in communities. I am trying to make the changes from this Edit Css [Make changes in communities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNh82.jpg). Please any one can guide me a little.

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons come from aura/lwc custom code you should be able to set CSS on that component's level and it'lll override community defaults.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm - empty file should be generated for you automatically

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css - there will be no empty file, create one in same directory as rest of component, with same name (`myComponent.js, myComponent.html` -> add `myComponent.css`). Here's a bit advanced example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/339936/799

If you're after community-wide change - in the Builder go to Security "tab" and there should be a menu to "edit head markup", you can paste some CSS overrides here. For example use this to hide Chatter "+ Follow" button on all pages. Since it's standard - you couldn't do it in component-level CSS.